# How remove specific div code from html using java or jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I want to remove the below 2 codes from my html on page load using java or jquery...

Important: I only want to remove these 2 lines - don't want to remove the content associated with it.

```html
<div id="left" style="width: 676px;">
```

```html
<table id="mainpage" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" cellspacing="0">
```

This is the link to my main code which has the above strings as well, [view code on this link](http://superbabyboutique.com/tablecode.txt)

Comment: `$("#mainpage, #left").remove()` ?

Comment: it removes the content associated with them as well...just want to remove this specific 2 lines while leaving the entire code as it is...

Comment: how to do that? send me the code...I have zero knowledge about all this...

Comment: Are you replacing this inside a text document.  What about it do you want changed?  Do you want the elemens unwrapped? (remove the surrounding relevant <div></div>

Comment: this code is basically in my product description on shopify...

Comment: http://superbabyboutique.com/tablecode.txt this is the entire code...and this is the screenshot of entire code > http://superbabyboutique.com/screenshot.jpg

So if I am able to remove the mainpage line in the code as mentioned above...I can get rid that white background behind the table...

But your answer actually removes the entire table along with mainpage line...

So just want to remove the white background behind the table as you see in the screenshot

Comment: I updated my answer, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#mainpage, #left").remove();
```

Or

```
$("#mainpage").attr('style', '');
$("#left").attr('style', '');
```

Or

```
var htmlInMainPage = $("#mainpage").html().remove();
$('table').append(htmlInMainPage);
```

Or explain better your question.

Comment: $("#left").attr('style', ''); worked....but $("#mainpage").attr('style', ''); did not worked for me...

Comment: this 'mainpage' id actually creates a border around my html table...if I remove this line - I can get rid of that border..so I want to use java or jquery to remove this particular line mentioned in the first post without affecting the entire content.

Comment: you tried with css? #mainpage{ border: 0; } or border-color:white;

Comment: http://superbabyboutique.com/tablecode.txt this is the entire code...and this is the screenshot of entire code > http://superbabyboutique.com/screenshot.jpg

So if I am able to remove the mainpage line in the code as mentioned above...I can get rid that white background behind the table...

But your answer actually removes the entire table along with mainpage line...

So just want to remove the white background behind the table as you see in the screenshot and that can be done if remove the mainpage line as mentioned in the first step

Answer (score 0):

If you know elements class or ID, you can use

```
display:none
```

If you know element order within the parent, for example third .btn

```
.btn-nth-of-type(3) {display:none}
```